# Svn up not updating/downloading dir that is managed by svn but doesn't exist locally

Tags: svn, version-control

Attempting to use svn up to pull the latest changes but one of the subdirectories is stubbornly refusing to get pulled despite having files tracked by svn in it.

`svn stat` shows the dir in question with a "?" as shown below:

```
?       dir/dir2electricboogaloo/somedir/otherdir/DIR_IN_QUESTION
```

`svn diff` doesn't log anything.

Attempting another svn up after all of the following steps says "At revision XXXX" and does nothing.

Tried:

- svn cleanup, it doesn't work
- svn revert /path, it doesn't work
- Deleting the highest-level dir managed by svn, it doesn't work

I can't think of next steps, can I get a hand?

Answer (score 0):

Status `?` means `Unversioned`. So this directory exists only locally in your working copy. It does not exist in the repository. Add it to Subversion using the `svn add` command and `svn commit` it so that it's tracked by Subversion and recorded in the repository.

Be careful with the contents of the directory - Subversion does not track its contents, it does not back it up. Again, since it has the `?` status, it's unversioned.